Flutter add AlertDialog to ElevatedButton.onPressed
I have a login button on  my app with this code:
class PublicHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PublicHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userDataNotifier = Provider.of<UserDataNotifier>(context);

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Please login',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: userDataNotifier.login,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: userDataNotifier.isLoading ? 0.2 : 1.0,
              child: const Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.login),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Text('Login'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

The UserDataNotifier class is using SharedPreferences in order to save user state. The login function looks like this:
class UserDataNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  final SharedPreferences prefs;
  bool _isLogged = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  UserData? _userData;

  bool get isLogged => _isLogged;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  UserData? get userData => _userData;

  Future<bool> login() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    var url = Uri.https('mydomain', 'api/login');

    // if there is no internet connection, throw an error
    try {
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var responseBody = response.body;

      // parse response and set user-data (on success)
      // or throw an error (on login failure)

      _isLogged = true;
      _isLoading = false;
      prefs.setBool('isLogged', _isLogged);
      notifyListeners();
      return true;

    } catch (e) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

I want to add en alertDialog if login fails (no internet connection, wrong credentials, etc.)
I tried to add it both on button and inside UserDataNotifier class, but neither works.
How should I add the alert?

Try below code, update your login() method
try {
  var response = await http.get(url);
  var responseBody = response.body;

 
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return 'Wrong credentials. Please try again.';
  }

  _isLogged = true;
  _isLoading = false;
  prefs.setBool('isLogged', _isLogged);
  notifyListeners();
  return null;
} catch (e) {
  _isLoading = false;
  notifyListeners();
  return 'No internet connection. Please try again later.';
}

Your onPressed function.
 onPressed: () async {
          String? errorMessage = await userDataNotifier.login();
          if (errorMessage != null) {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Login Failed'),
                content: Text(errorMessage),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('OK'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },


Great, it works. However, Visual Studio give me the following worning regarding to the context: context line: Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps. Try rewriting the code to not use the 'BuildContext', or guard the use with a 'mounted' . What should I do with it?

where you got this warning?

In showDialog( context: context,  the context: context is marked with a blue underline, and when I hover it I see this error/warning.

In my side I don't see any warning regarding context

https://imgur.com/a/7kbeHQl

Just scroll down the hovered suggestion box and try to click fix it button

The suggested quick-fix is Ignore 'use_build_context_synchronously' for this line (or for the whole file or in analysis_options.yaml)

use  Future function to use the AlertDialog.Refer the below example.
Call the function whenever you need AlertDialog.


Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: const SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Approve'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );



Refer more details on official doc here - AlertDialog

Where should I include it? The context variable is not defined (I get an error Undefined name 'context'.)

place it some where in the class (if StatefulWidget class , then in the state  class) and pass the BuildContext as a parameter when you call _showMyDialog.Make sure to accept  it as a parameter like here -
Future _showMyDialog(BuildContext context) async { ....

Alternatively you can place the _showMyDialog in Build() method.It already has the BuildContext.Then no modifications will be needed.
